# How to total Amount from group section header and footer in Crystal Reports

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, crystal-reports

Now this might be a very long to read, please read thoroughly..!

I am creating a report in Crystal Report in Visual Studio 2015. Database is SQL Server 2014.

Say, this is my data which the report uses, just for reference:

[image: DataBase]

I used the procedure for it, and I designed the procedure in such a way that if I insert date filter to procedure say of 02/05/2016 (DD/MM/YYYY) then the opening balance line displays on 02/05/2016.

(Just explaining to make it easy, it is connected with the report).

Now the following shows the structure of the report,

[image: Report Structure]

I added description in Section 2 (Page Header) to display Opening Balance at the first of the report.
 And I grouped the date monthly in it..
Following are the formulas I created in the report..

1. DebitAmt/CreditAmt - To display amount in appropriate section from Database i.e Debit or Credit in the field.
2. TotBal1 - Use to reset TotBal1 variable to 0 required for calculation, it is surpressed in section2 Page Header in Report Structure.

   Formula in TotBal1 contains:

   ```
   WhilePrintingRecords;
   NumberVar TotBal1;
   TotBal1 := 0
   ```
3. TotBal3 - It contains addition formula.

   Formula in TotBal3 contains:
   `WhilePrintingRecords;
   NumberVar TotBal1;
   TotBal1 := TotBal1 - {@DebitAmt} + {@CreditAmt}`

This following displays the report.!

[image: Report Output]

> Problems facing are mentioned below..

1. Now the problem is in Image 3, I am not getting the balance by placing TotBal3, it shows 0. I question Marked there with blue ink.
2. The summation at the end of the report doesn't include the 9502.53 Amount value (circled with blue ink below). I want to add that even in that total. Exact figure should be 53367.53.....

I have created that sum by in built summation tool in crystal report..
Please say if anything more required...!

Comment: Thank You Stack User for editing the grammar of the question

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use running totals (`whileprintingrecords` aggregating formulas) in group headers - they are not evaluated yet.

Create simple formula for single row balance, like `{@CreditAmt} - {@DebitAmt}` and use 'normal' aggregates (sum() over group) for it.

Comment: Will try it and say you what other difficulty I am facing..!

Comment: Hey, but I need running value for it...!

Comment: IMO you have two different problems here. For running total you can use Crystal Reports' native Running Total functionalty (you need to sum this C-D formula results), no need to sum inside formula - but this doesn't allow totals in group headers either. For Opening Balance (in page headers) you can use formula, assigning value to internal variable only once - at first record. Sorry my answer above was a bit generic.